# Angular 2 polyfills initializing takes too long

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I am pretty new to Front-end development and having some issue with angular2 app.

As you can see the timeline capture below, polyfills taks too long time ( almost 6 seconds ! )
[image: chrome timeline]
It seems not a normal. but,, I have no idea what can I do to decrease this polyfills time.

Some lines of the conf.

```
  // Add build specific plugins
  if (ENV === 'build') {
    config.plugins.push(
      // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#noerrorsplugin
      // Only emit files when there are no errors
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),

      // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#dedupeplugin
      // Dedupe modules in the output
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),

      // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin
      // Minify all javascript, switch loaders to minimizing mode
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          compress: { warnings: false }
      })
    );
  }
```

Whole webpack.config.js I use in my app.
https://gist.github.com/jeesim2/484186d630fedc9f42e264ca905ad123

My angular version

```
"@angular/common": "^2.0.1",
"@angular/compiler": "^2.0.1",
"@angular/core": "^2.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "^2.0.1",
"@angular/http": "^2.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.1",
"@angular/router": "^3.0.1",
```

webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin decreased package size to 70% but Page loading speed wasn't get faster. 
[image]

What cause this long page loading?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to angular2 single page app :). A2 is still IMHO in development state. This behaviour is normal, depends of OS/browser/components number rendering is taking some seconds. Since bundled file with A2/vendors/polyfills is about 800kb+ (minimalized) it take some time to read all to browser memory.

You can check that rendering is done quite fast but scripts can be runned in background for few more seconds after initialized. Even on fast PC it takes some time.

It is done by https://github.com/angular/zone.js/